# How to list all dlls loaded by a process with Python?

Tags: python, windows, dll

I want to list all the dlls loaded by a process, like this:

[image]

How could I get the information with Python on Windows?

Comment: I keep trying  to figure out how to do it with pywin32 but the documentation is nearly nonexistent and I'm not familiar enough with COM to know exactly where to start anyway.  But I have a sneaking suspicion that COM via pywin32 will be able to get this info.

Comment: @Daniel, its `win32process.EnumProcessModules()` etc. (normal Windows API, no COM). See answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [listdlls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656):

```
import os
os.system('listdlls PID_OR_PROCESS_NAME_HERE')
```

Answer (score 17):

Using the package [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) it is possible to get a portable solution! :-)

```
# e.g. finding the shared libs (dll/so) our python process loaded so far ...
import psutil, os
p = psutil.Process( os.getpid() )
for dll in p.memory_maps():
  print(dll.path)
```

Comment: rss: aka “Resident Set Size”, this is the non-swapped physical memory a process has  Rss: 又名“驻留集大小”，这是进程拥有的非交换物理内存

Answer (score 1):

With [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) already installed do like:

```
import win32api, win32process
for h in win32process.EnumProcessModules(win32process.GetCurrentProcess()):
    print(win32api.GetModuleFileName(h)
```

Use functions like `win32api.GetFileVersionInfo()`, `.EnumResourceNames()` ... on the dll paths to get dll attribute data.