# Matplotlib - Scipy/Sklearn Interaction - LinearRegression Error in scipy.linalg._flapack

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn, scipy, python-3.7

I am having some issues with the interaction between matplotlib and scipy.
This is my understanding of the situation:

1. The error consists in the `LinearRegression` fit of `sklearn` throwing the `SVD not converging error`
2. After some debugging the error is thrown by `scipy\linalg\basic.py` where the `dgesld` method returns an info value different from `0` (`-4` in this case). The `lapack_func` used is, in my case, the fortran flatpack `dgesld`.
3. The error seems to depend on both the numerosity of the input and the `pyplot` (`matplotlib`) code, in particular the methods `yticks`, `xticks`.
4. The error first occurred in a multilinear regression problem (info value in `scipy\linalg\basic.py` equal to 23, positive in this case) but I have written the following script to better outline the issue

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a = [0.27236845, 0.79433854, 0.05986454, 0.62736383, 0.5732594
    , 0.54175392, 0.92359127, 0.19913404, 0.17357701, 0.10225879
    , 0.94727807, 0.23766063, 0.92438574, 0.10981865, 0.18669187
    , 0.71337215, 0.17843819, 0.98693265, 0.80787247, 0.931572]

b = [1.68869178, 2.20448291, 1.64828788, 1.95276497, 1.23976119, 1.61260175
    , 1.32652345, 1.94535222, 1.37353248, 1.47830833, 1.08400723, 1.91091901
    , 1.63909271, 2.37494003, 1.64490261, 1.90403079, 1.81028796, 1.66986048
    , 1.65304452, 1.60747378]

for no_plot in [True, False]:
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        _a = a[:i + 2]
        _b = b[:i + 2]
        if not no_plot:
            bar_color = "blue"
            margin = 10
            y_label = x_label = None
            angle = 0
            title = "TestError"
            color_theme = (0 / 235, 32 / 235, 96 / 235)
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 6.8))
            plt.bar(_a, _b, color=bar_color)
            box = ax.get_position()
            ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + margin * box.height, box.width, box.height * (1 - margin)])
            plt.xticks(fontname="Cambria", color=color_theme, rotation=angle, fontsize=25)
            plt.yticks(fontname="Cambria", color=color_theme, fontsize=25)
            plt.title(title, fontname="Cambria", color=color_theme, fontsize=25)
            ax_output = plt.gca()
        try:
            reg = LinearRegression().fit(np.array(_a).reshape(-1, 1), _b)
            print("Success: {}, @ i={} with no_plot={}".format(reg.score(np.array(_a).reshape(-1, 1), _b), i, no_plot))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: {} @ i={} with no_plot={}".format(repr(e), i, no_plot))
```

When run on a Windows 10 machine with:

```
python version: 3.7.9
scipy version: 1.5.2
scikit-learn version: 0.23.2
numpy version: 1.19.2
matplotlib version: 3.3.2
```

and `_flapack.cp37-win_amd64`

The results are the following:

```
Success: 1.0, @ i=0 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.9524690407545247, @ i=1 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.9248909415334777, @ i=2 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.17921330631542143, @ i=3 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.1559357435898613, @ i=4 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.001129573837944875, @ i=5 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.008667658302087822, @ i=6 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.001674117195053615, @ i=7 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.011802146118754298, @ i=8 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.024141340568111902, @ i=9 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.04144995409093344, @ i=10 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.03301917468171267, @ i=11 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.0959782634092683, @ i=12 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.08847483030078473, @ i=13 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.06428117850391502, @ i=14 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.07033033186821203, @ i=15 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.06394158828230323, @ i=16 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.0640239869160919, @ i=17 with no_plot=True
Success: 0.06734590831873866, @ i=18 with no_plot=True
Success: 1.0, @ i=0 with no_plot=False
Success: 0.9524690407545247, @ i=1 with no_plot=False
Success: 0.9248909415334777, @ i=2 with no_plot=False
Success: 0.17921330631542143, @ i=3 with no_plot=False
Success: 0.1559357435898613, @ i=4 with no_plot=False
Success: 0.001129573837944875, @ i=5 with no_plot=False
Success: 0.008667658302087822, @ i=6 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=7 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=8 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=9 with no_plot=False<
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=10 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=11 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=12 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=13 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=14 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=15 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=16 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=17 with no_plot=False
Exception: ValueError('illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None') @ i=18 with no_plot=False
```

As far as the stacktrace is concerned:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File: "......./isla.py", line 36, in <module>
reg = LinearRegression().fit(np.array(_a).reshape(-1, 1), _b)
File "......\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 547, in fit
linalg.lstsq(X, y)
File "......\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 1224, in lstsq
% (-info, lapack_driver))
ValueError: illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None
```

Frankly, I am a little bit lost. Does anybody have any idea on the issue?

Comment: I meet the same problem. I think something in the last 6 months has broken sklearn

Comment: @Duke Le I figured out a way to work around the issue. This is not a real answer given that the I could not find the reason of the issue. I reinstalled everything with conda (python 3.8.5, numpy 1.9.1 matplotlib 3.3.1) and it worked fine as long as I run it via command line, in PyCharm it did not work due to the usuale PyCharm issues with dll imports, I created a specific folder with only the needed dlls and added it to PATH and this fixed the issues (without introducing other stuff), in order to discern which dlls were needed I followed this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39390519/14408241